# Yii2 cancel validation on the javascript side

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I need can opportunity enable/disable validation a form on the javascript side on event by  click for example.
I use activerecord for creating this form.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and maybe try to explain what you want to do a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply set `enableClientValidation` to `false` :

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
]);
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$enableClientValidation-detail